# How to activate newsletter under new customer page in admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

Does anyone knows how to activate the "Newsletter" tab and/or show the checkbox for newsletter subscription under the registration page in admin?

I know how to activate under frontend, but i need to show the checkbox on the "first" step under the admin section, BEFORE clicking the SAVE button.